# ! Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference on line

Tags: php

```
<?php foreach (json_decode($jsondata,true)['data']['best_selling_products']['products'] as $a){ 
if(mb_strlen($a['title_fa']) > 60){
 $three = "...";
}
echo '<div class="swiper-slide slider-item">
<div class="">
<a href="'.$con_website_url.'product/'.$con_tag_product.$a['id']."/".preg_replace('/\s+/', '-',str_replace(' ',null,str_replace('‌',null,str_replace(['-','.'],' ',$a['title_fa'])))).'">
<img src="'.$a['images']['main']['url']['0'].'" alt="'.$a['title_fa'].'"></a>
<p class="slider-item-title">'.implode(' ', array_splice(explode(' ', $a['title_fa']),0,13)).$three.'</p>
<a href="'.$con_website_url.'product/'.$con_tag_product.$a['id']."/".preg_replace('/\s+/', '-',str_replace(' ',null,str_replace('‌',null,str_replace(['-','.'],' ',$a['title_fa'])))).'"> View </a>
</div>
</div>'."\n"; } ?>
```

Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference line 199

```
<p class="slider-item-title">'.implode(' ', array_splice(explode(' ', $a['title_fa']),0,13)).$three.'</p>
```

Any ideas? After 2 days still stuck.

Comment: Don't try to nest all that code. Split it up before your echo. Specifically, [array_splice](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) passes the array by reference, so you can't nest `explode` inside it

Comment: array_splice() see how to use it In your case, the expression explode(' ', $a['title_fa']) returns an array, and passing it directly to array_splice can result in the notice you're seeing. To resolve this issue, you can assign the result of explode to a variable before passing it to array_splice. Here's the modified code:

Comment: $titleFaArray = explode(' ', $a['title_fa']);
$slicedTitleArray = array_splice($titleFaArray, 0, 13);